# Javascript Object Creation inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

i have been trying to create objects inside a loop. Below is my code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="personDetails">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="Name1">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="Age1">
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="personDetails">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="Name2">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="Age2">
</div>
<button onclick="getDetails()">Check Value</button>
</div>
```

And below is the javascript..

```
function getDetails(){
var myObj = {};
$('.personDetails').each(function(){
        $(this).children().each(function(){
myObj[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
            });
    });
console.log(myObj);
}
```

And below is what it looks like in console. but i dont want it all into one object. what i want is each person should have each object created in that .each loop. i know i m close but cant figure out what i am doing wrong.

```
Object {Name1: "cfr", Age1: "15", Name2: "fgatat", Age2: "25"}
```

I want to do like

```
person1 {Name: "cfr", Age: "15"}, 
person2 {Name: "fgatat", Age: "25"}
```

Comment: Create an Array outside the loop, create each new object inside the loop, and add each new object to the array.

Comment: I was doing that but i am messing it all up.. Please advise if you can just copy paste the function it should be like. Sorry for trouble and Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Generally you use inputs to gather data from the user, and use that data for something, for instance sending it to a server, and then you would'nt do it this way at all, you'd just serialize the inputs instead

Comment: i dont want to use form, all the div named personDetails will be added dynamically through jquery depending on how many div's they want, then when the button is clicked, i want to loop through every field and filter its value and they will of course send to server using $.ajax. server side script knows how many objects he is expecting and will loop through all of them and store in database. one posted object will have one or more objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one of possible solutions:

```
function getDetails(){
  var myObj = [];
  $('.personDetails').each(function() {
        var person = {};
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            person[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        });
        myObj.push(person)
    });
   console.log(myObj);
}
```

Comment: But will you not still have different keys within the objects for each person, like `name1`, `name2` etc.?

Comment: Yes. But now numbering may be removed from those IDs during creation. Or any other trick may be done.

Comment: actually i wont be using id, will get data using name attr. and every object will have name and age

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a `var` with `window[myvar]`

```js
function getDetails(){
$('.personDetails').each(function(i){
  i+=1;
  window["person"+i] = {};
  $(this).children().each(function(){
    window["person"+i][$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
  });
});
console.log(person1);
console.log(person2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="personDetails">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="Name1">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="Age1">
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="personDetails">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="Name2">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="Age2">
</div>
<button onclick="getDetails()">Check Value</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this, that gives you exactly the output you're asking for

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var result = $('.personDetails').toArray().reduce(function(a, b, i) {
    return a['person' + (++i)] = {
      Name: $(b).find('[id^=Name]').val(),
      Age: $(b).find('[id^=Age]').val()
    }, a;
  }, {});

  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="personDetails">
    <input type="text" class="abc" id="Name1">
    <input type="text" class="abc" id="Age1">
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="personDetails">
    <input type="text" class="abc" id="Name2">
    <input type="text" class="abc" id="Age2">
  </div>
  <button id="btn">Check Value</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ids are always in the same form `NameX` and `AgeX`, you can update your code to extract only the `Name` and `Age` parts using `$(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, '')` and use them as properties.

This is how should be your code:

```
function getDetails() {
  var results = [];
  $('.personDetails').each(function() {
    var person = {};
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      person[$(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, '')] = $(this).val();
    });
    results.push(person)
  });
  console.log(results);
}
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo snippet:

```js
function getDetails() {
  var results = [];
  $('.personDetails').each(function() {
    var person = {};
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      person[$(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, '')] = $(this).val();
    });
    results.push(person)
  });
  console.log(results);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="personDetails">
    <input type="text" class="abc" id="Name1">
    <input type="text" class="abc" id="Age1">
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="personDetails">
    <input type="text" class="abc" id="Name2">
    <input type="text" class="abc" id="Age2">
  </div>
  <button onclick="getDetails()">Check Value</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the following, add a name to your input that uses the following format *inputName[index]*. So that you can extract the code using indexes. The selector to extract the value from the input would be something along the lines of `'input[name="inputName[' + index + ']"'`. Then all you need to to is use this in for loop. You might even have a function that generates all your fields based on a jQuery function.

```js
(function($) {
  //Object
  function Person(name, age) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.age = age;
    return self;
  }

//actual getDetails function
  function getDetails() {
    var myObj = [];
    var name, age; //These vars are added for readabilitys sake. You could place them directly in the new Person()
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      
      name = $('input[name="Name[' + i + ']"').val();
      age = $('input[name="Age[' + i + ']"').val();
      myObj.push(new Person(name, age));
    }

    console.log(myObj);
  }

 //Click Binding
  $("#getDetails").on('click', getDetails);

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="personDetails">
    <input type="text" class="abc" name="Name[0]">
    <input type="text" class="abc" name="Age[0]">
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="personDetails">
    <input type="text" class="abc" name="Name[1]">
    <input type="text" class="abc" name="Age[1]">
  </div>
  <div class="personDetails">
    <input type="text" class="abc" name="Name[2]">
    <input type="text" class="abc" name="Age[2]">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="getDetails">Check Value</button>
</div>
```